# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myApp' deploying django on planethoster with n0c

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'm struggling with n0c and wsgi (with passenger), it works in developpment but not while deploying

The error message

```
/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import sys, os, io, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/passenger/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/opt/alt/python310/lib64/python3.10/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/kriill/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kriill.src.kriill.wsgi
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/kriill/kriill/src/kriill/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/virtualenv/kriill/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/virtualenv/kriill/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/virtualenv/kriill/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ambnvnpa/virtualenv/kriill/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/opt/alt/python310/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'home'
```

passenger_wsgi.py
I added the multiple dots at the difference of the tutorial (https://kb.planethoster.com/guide/astuces-techniques/installer-django-sur-world/)
because of my folder architecture.

```
import kriill.src.kriill.wsgi
application = kriill.src.kriill.wsgi.application
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kriill.src.kriill.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

````
import os
import environ

from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env(env_file=str(BASE_DIR / "kriill" / ".env"))


SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = env.bool("DEBUG", False) 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("ALLOWED_HOSTS") 

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'embed_video',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kriill.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kriill/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kriill.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),

    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
        messages.DEBUG: 'alert-secondary',
        messages.INFO: 'alert-info',
        messages.SUCCESS: 'alert-success',
        messages.WARNING: 'alert-warning',
        messages.ERROR: 'alert-danger',
 }

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "mediafiles"

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
FROM_EMAIL = env('FROM_EMAIL') 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL') 
EMAIL_BACKEND = env('EMAIL_BACKEND') 
EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = env('EMAIL_USE_TLS') 
EMAIL_PORT = env('EMAIL_PORT') 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD') ```

Any ideas?
````

Comment: in `settings.py`, under `INSTALLED_APPS`, you have `home` listed -- is that supposed to be there? And your question title mentions `myApp`, but that doesn't show up in any of your pastes

Comment: home is the name of my django application, so I called it a generic way in the title.
in django when you create a new app you have to put it in the array "INSTALLED_APPS"